# python beautifulsoup multiprocessing error

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def display(urls):
    for u in urls:
        page = requests.get(u)
        c = page.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
        row = soup.find_all("table",{"style":"width: 500px;"})[0].find_all('tr')
        dict = {}
        for i in row:
            for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={
            'style':'color: #008000;'}):
                dict['Title'] = title.text
            for link in i.find_all('a',attrs={'title':'UPSC'}, href=True):
                dict['Link'] = link['href']
                print(dict)


from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
results = pool.map(display(['http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-18/33742/','http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019']))
```

Output AND errors:

```
{'Title': 'Corrigendum', 'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Corrigendum-UPSC-Administrative-Officer-Lecturer-Posts.pdf'}
{'Title': ' Apply Online', 'Link': 'https://upsconline.nic.in/ora/VacancyNoticePub.php'}
{'Title': 'Notification ', 'Link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Notification-UPSC-Administrative-Officer-Lecturer-Posts.pdf'}
{'Title': ' Official Website', 'Link': 'http://www.upsc.gov.in/ '}
{'Title': 'Apply Online', 'Link': 'https://upsconline.nic.in/upsc/mainmenu2.php'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask.py", line 94, in <module>
    results = pool.map(display(['http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-18/33742/','http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019']))
TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
```

Here i have implemented multiprocessing in python.
but, it is giving result along with some error.

result is giving as expected but some error is giving AFTER THAT..

Comment: Have you read the docs for `ThreadPool.map`? You should be able to fix this quickly once you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ThreadPool.map` incorrectly. You need to pass both the function `display` and the list with your urls. Also, you don't need a for-loop in your `display()` since map will apply the function to every url of the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def display(url):
  page = requests.get(u)
  c = page.content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
  row = soup.find_all("table",{"style":"width: 500px;"})[0].find_all('tr')
  dict = {}
  for i in row:
      for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={
      'style':'color: #008000;'}):
          dict['Title'] = title.text
      for link in i.find_all('a',attrs={'title':'UPSC'}, href=True):
          dict['Link'] = link['href']
          print(dict)


from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
results = pool.map(display, ['http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-18/33742/', 'http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019'])
```

Comment: Thanks bro. it is working . It is coming one after another. how to get all at once.

Comment: I mean for one url how much time it is taking it should take same time for morethan  urls.. is that possible??